# How to divide total days output by individual year in python so that total days doesn't effect one particular year

Tags: python, function, dataframe, datetime

Iam currently working on analyzing the delay in the response to a request made to each department. Format of data is as below:

```
Department     RequestDate     ResponseDate 
Electronics    2019-05-01      2019-09-19
Babyshop       2018-08-02      2019-09-30
Grocery        2016-01-01      2018-01-01
Pharmacy       2015-03-01      2018-03-01
```

What iam trying to accomplish is divide total days into respective years. The expected output is as below:

```
Department     RequestDate     ResponseDate   2015  2016  2017  2018  2019    TotalDays
Electronics    2019-05-01      2019-09-19      0      0    0     0     149     149
Babyshop       2018-08-02      2019-09-30      0      0    0     152   272     424
Grocery        2016-01-01      2018-01-01      0      365  365   1     0       731
Pharmacy       2015-03-01      2018-03-01      306    365  365   60    0       1096
```

currently my workflow is in excel and it is tidious. Is there any way to make use of python functions.

Comment: Since 2016 was a leap year, shouldn't it have 366 days instead of 365?

Comment: @Mark Ransom That was typo

Comment: @ganeshghimire as you have said it was typo , i have edited my code, also while calculating the difference in  days for individual years you seem to have kept the final days, which is reflected in each years column but not in the **TotalDays** column, I suggest that you edit these typos otherwise it would result in confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried my best to include every boundary condition in the solution. As far as index are concerned I think you can take care of that.

```
import calendar as cd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['RequestDate','ResponseDate'])
df.RequestDate = [pd.Timestamp('2019-05-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-08-02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2015-03-01')]
df.ResponseDate = [pd.Timestamp('2019-09-19'), pd.Timestamp('2019-09-30'), pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2018-03-01')]


df['TotalDays']=(df.ResponseDate-df.RequestDate).dt.days+1  #This is done coz it
#  seems in sample data, that the day corresponding to **ResponseDate**
# has also been counted when it comes to number of days for each years 
year_min = df['RequestDate'].min().year
year_max = df['ResponseDate'].max().year
years = [i for i in range(year_min,year_max+1)]


for i in years:
    df[i]=0
df.columns=['RequestDate','ResponseDate', 'TotalDays', *years]
l=[]


for i in range(len(years)-1):
    z=[]
    for item, row in df.iterrows():
        row[years[i]] = (min(row['ResponseDate'], pd.Timestamp(f'{years[i]+1}-01-01'))-max(row['RequestDate'], pd.Timestamp(f'{years[i]-1}-12-31'))).days
        if cd.isleap(years[i])==True:
            if row[years[i]]<=0:
                row[years[i]]=0
            elif row[years[i]]>366:
                row[years[i]]=366
        else:
            if row[years[i]]<=0:
                row[years[i]]=0
            elif row[years[i]]>365:
                row[years[i]]=365

        z.append(row[years[i]])
    l.append(z)


for i in range(len(years)-1):
    df[years[i]]=l[i]
df[years[-1]]=df['TotalDays']-df.iloc[:, 3:-1].sum(axis=1)
df=df[['RequestDate','ResponseDate',*years,'TotalDays']]
df
```

there could be better answers, but I can't think of them. Does this work in your all cases?

Comment: In case of Index , they can have any arbitrary values, therefore I have not included them.If you have any concerns regarding that , you can write in comment.

Comment: Iam having issue in cases where cases are not closed. for example if request is made from 2014-01-01 and it is still open. instead of assigning the value 365 to each year from 2014 it is returning blank.

Comment: how would you modify this if calculation were to be done by Fiscal Year

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment here is an answer.

So  my idea to make this frame would use DateTime and pandas. Supposing your data is on a csv file: 'yourfile.csv':

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

your_data = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

def take_columns(date):
    '''
    Transform the columns into datetime type
    '''
    date = datetime(*(time.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')[:6]))
    return date

def count_year(start, end):
    ''' 
    Returns a dict, with the years as keys, and the 
    days of that year as value 
    '''
    yearsDict = {}
    delta = end-start
    while delta.days>0:
        if end.year > start.year:
            new_year = datetime(start.year+1,1,1,0,0)
            days_year = new_year - start
            yearsDict[start.year] = yearsDict.get(start.year, days_year.days)
            start = new_year
            delta = end - new_year
        elif end.year == start.year:
            new_year = datetime(start.year,1,1,0,0)
        if delta.days<365:
            yearsDict[new_year.year] = yearsDict.get(new_year.year, delta.days)
            break
    return yearsDict



your_data = your_data.set_index(['Department']) #set the index of the DataFrame
new_columns = set() #to add the new columns with the years

#here we transform the columns into datetime format
your_data['RequestDate'] = your_data['RequestDate'].apply(lambda x: take_columns(str(x)))
your_data['ResponseDate'] = your_data['ResponseDate'].apply(lambda x: take_columns(str(x)))

#now we're gonna read the RequestDate column to make a set with the years
#the set is to avoid repeat the years
your_data['RequestDate'].apply(lambda x: new_columns.add(x.year))

#and create the columns
for column_name in range(min(new_columns), max(new_columns)+1):
    your_data[column_name] = 0

your_data['TotalDays'] = your_data['ResponseDate'] - your_data['RequestDate'] #this is for the 'TotalDays' column

#and finally we add the values on the years
for row in your_data.index:
    years = count_year(your_data.loc[row]['RequestDate'],your_data.loc[row]['ResponseDate'])
    for year in years:
        your_data.at[row,year] = years[year]
```

Now you can export the result('your_data') to a file for example:

```
your_data.to_csv('your_new_file.csv')
```

don't know if is the best way but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function that can return the number of days in each year between two `datetime.datetime` objects.

```
def days_per_year(dt1, dt2):
    ''' Return a list of years and number of days in that year
        occurring in the range between dt1 and dt2.
    '''
    # remove hours,minutes,seconds to turn these into pure dates
    dt1 = dt1.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
    dt2 = dt2.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
    if dt1 > dt2:
        dt1, dt2 = dt2, dt1 # swap if out of order
    ret = []
    for y in range(dt1.year, dt2.year + 1):
        year_end = min(dt2, datetime.datetime(y + 1, 1, 1))
        year_start = max(dt1, datetime.datetime(y, 1, 1))
        ret.append((y, (year_end - year_start).days))
    return ret

>>> for RequestDate, ResponseDate in (('2019-05-01','2019-09-19'),('2018-08-02','2019-09-30'),('2016-01-01','2018-01-01'),('2015-03-01','2018-03-01')):
    RequestDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(RequestDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    ResponseDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(ResponseDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print(RequestDate, ResponseDate, days_per_year(RequestDate, ResponseDate))

2019-05-01 00:00:00 2019-09-19 00:00:00 [(2019, 141)]
2018-08-02 00:00:00 2019-09-30 00:00:00 [(2018, 152), (2019, 272)]
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 00:00:00 [(2016, 366), (2017, 365), (2018, 0)]
2015-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:00:00 [(2015, 306), (2016, 366), (2017, 365), (2018, 59)]
```

It's unclear if you want the last day to count or not, half your examples do but half don't.

Comment: either or that doesn't really matter.

Comment: how would it work if it is fiscal year. if we are trying to acheive same thing except for the fiscal year.

Comment: @ganeshghimire I don't think Python has any concept of a fiscal year, so you're on your own.